# Dealing with obstinacy of commenters

Tags: discussion

Is there a procedure for alerting moderators (without whining) when a commenter appears to be singularly obstinate and disagreeable? I'm thinking, for example, of when a commenter keeps insisting that something is in an OP that actually is not.

I'll be happy to be more specific, but I'd like to be sure that I'm respecting site rules first.

Comment: The best you can do is flag as “no longer needed”, disengage, and walk away. The price you’ll have to pay for this wonderful outcome is not having the last word. But it’s kind of like loaning $20 to that guy you don’t like and you know he’ll never pay back: you also know he’ll avoid you because he has no intention of repaying you. So you paid $20 to get him out of your life. Now, of course, if this person is not just obstinate but rude and/or abusive, you should use *that* flag, which mods will definitely prioritize and use for further investigation of the user and his behavior patterns.

Comment: Thanks, @DanBron, I certainly will disengage.

Comment: There is also the option which states: “It’s unfriendly or unkind.
*This comment is rude or condescending*. “ which appears to be closer to the behavior that you are describing.

Comment: And that's not considered whining? Silly question. I guess it isn't, since it's offered as an option.

Comment: Remember  to check later if the flag has been marked as useful or rejected by mods.

Comment: You shouldn't view flagging content that is "unfriendly" as whining. It's important to bring potentially unfriendly comments to the attention of the moderators so they can be nipped in the bud. Leaving that tone hanging around on the site can cause more of it. https://news.stanford.edu/2017/02/06/stanford-research-shows-anyone-can-become-internet-troll/ It's unlikely that you are the only person that will be affected by those comments, so flagging them is actually helping the site, not whining.

Comment: Thanks, @ColleenV. Update for all: Before I could get to it, the moderators noticed the whole thing and moved the conversation to chat. It should be pretty easy to find.

Comment: Sadly, in EL&U there are a few (and it is very few) long term users who ask very few questions, give very few answers, yet have a lot to say, most of it sarcastic, by way of comment. I am surprised it is tolerated. When I first posted on EL&U, almost three years ago, I had the distinct impression that these people were 'gate-keepers' who deliberately made new users 'run the gauntlet' of sarcasm as a kind of 'initiation' process. Sad, really. But persevere, and take no notice of the thoughtless : you will find it is worth it.

Comment: Thank you, @NigelJ. I have certainly noticed that, and I could tell you who they are. It's unfortunate that people who wouldn't dare speak that way to people in person feel that all types of derision are allowed online. I love the site, though, and when there are good conversations, they are genuinely ineresting.